# hooking up Intruments trace file with Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, instruments

My colleague found a leak I don't see. So he sent me the trace file showing the leak. 
I wonder how can I hook up that trace with my xcode project? so when I can see the part of the code in my project. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using Xcode4 but my colleague used Xcode 3.2 with instruments I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what version of Xcode you're using, but the following will test if it's possible to open your Xcode project with the version of Instruments that ships with Xcode 4:

Switch to the call tree in the trace file. Find one of your program's methods in the call tree. Double-click the method. The trace document window should show the method's source code. Above the source code is a set of four buttons.

[image: Instruments source view buttons]

Clicking the button with the Xcode icon should open the file in Xcode. You may want to have your Xcode project open before you click the button.

If you can't see any source code when you double-click the method in the call tree, you should try creating a source tree. A source tree lets multiple people access the files in an Xcode project. By creating a source tree your colleague and you would be accessing the same files, which would increase the chances of being able to connect the trace file to your Xcode project.